# Android: extracting and replacing text with a spannable clickable text

Tags: android, regex, textview, spannablestring

I have some text in a list view. The format of each text contains a (1 or more) user's name inside as in:

`This is a message for @[Joe Bloggs](id:100), hi how are you, from @[John Doe](id:50). I am fine.`

I need to replace it with the following:

`This is a message for @Joe Bloggs, hi how are you, from @John Doe. I am fine.`

When you click on the user's name it should open an activity passing in the user's id.

What is the REGEX and logic that i need to do this operation, and what is the most efficient way of extracting the username and id, and replacing the text with the user's name in a clickable spannable text to open the activity with the user's id.

Bearing in mine, this is in a list view.

Thanks.

Comment: use `Spannable#setSpan` with a custom `ClickableSpan`, i will not help you with the regex thou

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://zunostudios.com/blog/development/176-how-to-implment-hashtags-and-callouts-in-android